# What is the best practice for kdump disk size

Tags: linux, memory, crash-dumps

We have a `redhat 6` servers and memory is around `64GB`, we are planing to configure `kdump` and I am confused about disk size I should set. Redhat suggest it would be `memory + 2% more` (that means around ~66GB Disk space). I need your suggestion what would be the best size I should define for kdump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't enable kdump unless Redhat support tells you to.  KDumps don't really produce anything useful for most Linux 'customers'.

Second, kdump could (potentially) dump the entire contents of RAM into the dump file.  If you have 64GB of RAM ..AND.. it is full when the kdump is triggered, then yes, the space for your kdump file will need to be what RH suggested.  That said, most problems can be identified with partial kdumps.  RH support has even said before to perform 'head -c ' on the file before sending it in to reduce its size.  Usually trimming it down to the first 64MBs.

Finally, remember to disable kdumps after you have finished trouble-shooting the issue.  This isn't something you want running constantly on any system above a 'Development/Test' level.  Most importantly is to remember to clean this space out after a kdump has occurred.

Comment: I can't disagree more about not having kdump enabled on a production environment. To arrive at a solid root cause for an unexpected hang / reboot issue, you need a vmcore. This is non-negotiable, and I always recommend having kdump enabled on EVERY production and test system. Would you rather have one downtime having kdump enabled, or two customer-impacting downtimes (the first incident, and then hopefully reproducing the second).

Comment: That would depend on the importance of your production systems.  Having kdump enabled doesn't normally impact system performance, though it can, if memory usage is an issue on the system.  As it does impact available memory.  More importantly, the required reboot could not happen until AFTER the system has created the (usually very large), dump file.  In my production environment, any unexpected hang/reboot is handled by:  1> use the fastest possible recovery method (which means no kdumps) and 2> schedule a full hardware swap at the soonest possible maintenance window.

Comment: I disagree with your advice to trim the core down with "head". Nobody captures gigabytes of data to only use the first 64Mb. That advice might have been valid for *your specific* case, but in general a full core with `-d1` on makedumpfile is the most useful. For many issues, this level of core may be required to come to a definite conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the system has enough memory, the kdump crash recovery service will not be operational. For the information on minimum memory requirements, refer to the Required minimums section of the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Technology capabilities and limits comparison chart. When kdump is enabled, the minimum memory requirements increase by the amount of memory reserved for it. This value is determined by a user, and when the crashkernel=auto option is used, it defaults to 128 MB plus 64 MB for each TB of physical memory (that is, a total of 192 MB for a system with 1 TB of physical memory).

In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, the crashkernel=auto only reserves memory if the system has 4 GB of physical memory or more.

To configure the amount of memory that is reserved for the kdump kernel, as root, open the /boot/grub/grub.conf file in a text editor and add the crashkernel=M (or crashkernel=auto) parameter to the list of kernel options

Comment: How much disk space i need? If i have 64GB RAM?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before.

The amount of memory reserved for the kdump kernel can be estimated with the following scheme:

> base memory to be reserved = 128MB
>    an additional 64MB added for each
>   TB of physical RAM present in the system. 
>   So  for example if a system
>   has 1TB of memory 192MB (128MB + 64MB) will be reserved.

So I believe 128MB will be sufficient in your case.

You may want to have a look at this link [Configuring crashkernel on RHEL6.2 (and later) kernels](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/59432)